# Creating a Scatter Plot with different colors for a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm currently trying to create a scatter plot with certain traits.
My original 'eu' contains countries with city statistics like longitude, latitude, region, etc.
I created a dataframe with where the country is grouped with the cities that it contains while showing their longitude and latitude at the same time.

```
cityScatter = eu[['country', 'city', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'temperature']] # Create a new dataframe to hold specific items.
newCityScatter = cityScatter.groupby(['country', 'city', 'longitude', 'latitude']).count()['temperature'].to_frame() # Group the countries with their respective cities.
newCityScatter = newCityScatter.drop(['temperature'], axis=1) # Remove temperature now that we have it grouped.
newCityScatter # Result
```

[image]

This is the table I get. It's what I want since all the countries are grouped together with the cities.
Now my problem comes with creating a scatter plot.
I want the graph to have x = longitude and y = latitude for each city. However, the country the city resides in must have its own color on the graph.

For example, Graz, Innsbruck, and Linz could be colored blue since they reside in Austria. Meanwhile, Edinburgh, Exter, Glasgow, Inverness, and Swansea could be red since they reside in the United Kingdom.

```
newCityScatter.plot(kind='scatter',x='longitude',y='latitude')
```

When I run the above statement, I get "TypeError: no numeric data to plot".
I want to figure out how I can get a scatter plot up with these contraints on.

DISCLAIMER: I CANNOT use seaborn. I want to figure out how to do this with only matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `.groupby()` or any other preprocessing.

I think you could just do:

```py
cityScatter.plot(kind='scatter', x='longitude', y='latitude', c='country')
```

Comment: I've tried doing that, but every time it will give me an error stating that it's not a valid color argument. It's strange too because I see other posts where it works for other people, but no matter what I do, it will just give an error.

Comment: Oh right - strings can't be interpreted as colors. They have to be converted to numbers first. I think one quick thing you could try would be: `cityScatter["country_hash"] = cityScatter["country"].map(hash) and use that as a numerical value. But that's only a quick approach, in practice I would then look for another way to do the conversion to numbers

Comment: I guess that could work. If I have time, I'll see if I can come up with something. For now, I'm just gonna use (c=newCityScatter['country'].map({'Albania':'red','Andorra':'blue', 'Austria':'green', ........). It's messy, tedious, and I had to write it for every single country, but in the end, it worked. Thanks for the help!